# Multiple actions were found that match the request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I m new to WebAPI and just exploring its default sample "value" controller which is there out of box with project.

I see it was already having two Get methods:

```
      // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

I tried and changed int id with a complex type and received "**Multiple actions were found that match the request**"

Why is that it was working fine beofre ?

My route is defuatl:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I m passing a complex object in body using Get methoed, I know it is not Restful way but please help me understand it.

Much appreciated.

Comment: why would you pass a complex object to a GET method? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Just exploring why I can't send a complex obj with Get

Comment: You can, but you'd then need to map what that object is, such as Get (ObjectType thing)

Comment: because GET method reads data from the querystring of the request url. There is a limitation on how much data you can send via querystring. On the other hand, POST requests read data from the request body in which you can send anything

Comment: sort of true, but MVC will actually try to POST to that depending on what you're doing (ajax or whatever) - the method name Get is actually not required. To force a get request only, you can decorate it with [HttpGet]

Comment: @Nikki9696 how I can map tha object ? Where and how please guide

Comment: @Shyju, my object is not very big, just 5-6 properties but still it is complex type. why I can't do it ? do it need to put it in querystring manually ? I m passing it in body. thx

Comment: Why are you not using a HttpPost method ? They were created for this use case.

Comment: Kinda a big topic, but here's a few things about how routing works, which is the basics of your question http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions

Comment: Also, I agree with @Shyju, I would POST an object. GET should be simple with ids and stuff, not just to be restful but just to be easier and saner  =)  as it's how the framework is really meant to be used out of the box

Comment: You can get fancy later and do fun things if you need to, but understanding the basics of how it's meant to work will make putzing with it easier if it's not working like you want or you need to have custom attributes, routing, etc for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActionName` annotation for this issue. For example use:

```
 [ActionName("IEnumerableGet")]
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

So you can call `IEnumerableGet` to have this method get called.